# Numerical Double Integration with Apache Common Math in Java

Tags: java, math, integral

```
    final UnivariateFunction integrand = f -> Math.exp(3 *
            (C[0] * Math.pow(f, 2)) +
            (C[1] * g * f) +
            (C[2] * g * f) +
            (C[3] * Math.pow(g, 2))
    );
```

(I do not how to define g as the second integral value)
If it were  not a double integration, I could have solved it like this

```
   final UnivariateIntegrator integrator = new SimpsonIntegrator();
   final double res = integrator.integrate(100, integrand, 0, 10);
   System.out.println(res);
```

But I could not find how to do it for double integrals.

For the sake of simplicity, how is it done to calculate this in apache common math library?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just nest the integrations, so first you define a function that for a given c returns the integral of x^2 + cx + c^2 between 0 and 2pi, and then you integrate that function for the interval [0, 1]

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.